# How to use lineend in positive lookahead?

Tags: java, regex

https://regex101.com/r/0DT5zE/2

In the following example, I want to match line 1, 2 and 5.

```
-STARTxxx-END
-STARTxxx-
-STARTxxx#END
-STARTxxx#
-STARTxxx
```

Using regex: `-START(?=(?:xxx[-$]))`

In words: after the `-START` tag, there should be `xxx`, followed by either a dash `-` or the lineend `$`.

Question: why doesn't the last line produce a match? What am I missing when using the lineend `$`?

Comment: `$` in a character set matches the character `$`, alternate instead

Comment: Use `-START(?=xxx(?:-|$))`. Or `-START(?=xxx(?![^-]))` (in actual code).